# 'That solved my problem!' doesn't work for deleted questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

Don't display the banner when the question is deleted. This is persistent, despite a refresh.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Oooo, maybe we can find a duplicate of this and make it look all inception like. ;)

Comment: @bluefeet http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqM2x.png

Comment: "Self Destruct" near your comment. I wonder, how many deleted comments do you make?

Comment: @TravisJ I recently installed the script. I don't delete many, and those that I do go pretty quick. I don't have exact numbers. Maybe 1 a day on average?